# How to write a method where 2 numbers are fed to the input, and the values of these 2 cells of the array are swapped?

Tags: swap, remix

For example an array
[1, 2, 3, 4]

I call the method and give 2 and 3 there. The function swaps cells 2 and 3, as a result, the array becomes [1, 2, 4, 3]

Question: How to write a method where 2 numbers are fed to the input, and the values of these 2 cells of the array are swapped?

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract MassiveExample {
uint [] number = [1585, 180, 1478, 16];